# How to open app's notification settings in settings app Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to Open the app's notification settings but it only goes to the settings screen.
I want it to work on all versions.

Below is my code

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,
           let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.notificationSettingsURLString! + bundleIdentifier) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
extension UIApplication {
 static let notificationSettingsURLString: String? = {
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
      return UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString
    }

    if #available(iOS 15.4, *) {
      return UIApplicationOpenNotificationSettingsURLString
    }

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
      // just opens settings
      return UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
    }

    return nil
  }()
}
```

I want when the button is pressed it goes to the app's notification settings

Comment: Prior to iOS 15.4 Apple didn't provide a way to go to the notification settings so it can't be done.

Comment: @HangarRash My current device is iOS 16, I'm thinking that Apple doesn't support it